# pci_alloc_consistent implicit function declaration when installing driver

Tags: drivers, software-installation, compiling, make, pci

I'm trying to install the drivers from source code for a LinksTek PCIE-SE2 card (http://linkstek.com/showproduct.php?id=239).  I haven't gotten a response from their support, so I'm posting here.  I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.  When I run the make file, I'm getting this error:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'pci_alloc_consistent'
```

Is this because that function is absolute and no longer part of the linux generic headers?  Any idea what I can do to get a good compile?

Aaron

Comment: The compiler tells that it has not found a definition of that symbol/function. My judgment of this error; you need to find where `pci_alloc_consistent` is defined and make sure that code gets included in the build. A `grep -r pci_alloc_consistent *` at the root of the build tree (folder) might include it, but it is likely to be among all references to it.

Comment: Please include your kernel version (`uname -r`). Did you install the appropriate linux-headers package for your system (usually it is sufficient to install `linux-headers-generic`)? The `pci_alloc_consistent` declaration should be found there, ex. `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/pci-dma-compat.h`